# Building a MYSQL query based on multiple unique listings

Tags: php, sql, mysql

Sorry for the crappy title - didn't know how else to say it.

I have a commenting database where anyone can report a comment for abuse (anyone as in not just logged in members).  This obviously means a person could report a comment multiple times.  Where I need help is building a query that shows the number of times a comment has been reported but by unique email address AND ip address.

I'm not sure if that is clear or not -- if joe@joe.com of IP address 1.2.3.4 reports a message more than once, it will only count as one report.  If there is an additional record of joe@joe.com with an IP of 4.5.6.7 reporting the same comment, it would count as two reports since the IPs are different.

The fields, all in one table:

- id
- comment_id
- note
- email
- ip_address

I hope that all makes sense and any help would be GREATLY appreciated!

Comment: Why would you want to allow multiples?  [Put a unique constraint on both columns](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)

Comment: Forgive my simpleness but I want records with exact matches of email AND IP to be counted only once for any given comment (comment_id)

Comment: Could you please post some sample data and the recordset you'd like to get?

Comment: @OMGPonies: sometimes you need to log everything. We had almost the same problem with duplicate `SMS` that don't count as separate messages for the business logic but need to be stored nevertheless for dealing with the aggregator.

Comment: Misread your comment OMG Ponies -- I don't want multiples but that's the way the DB came to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  email, ip_address, COUNT(DISTINCT note)
FROM    log
GROUP BY
        email, ip_address
```

**Update:**

As per your comment, I believe you want this:

```
SELECT  comment_id, COUNT(DISTINCT email, ip_address)
FROM    log
GROUP BY
        comment_id
```

Comment: What does the (DISTINCT note) do versus Daniel's (*)?

Comment: If `joe` submits three reports: "spam", "spam", "ham"; "spam" will be counted only once.

Comment: You updated query worked like a champ.  Thanks so much!I love S.O.!!

Comment: Pff, reading is an art, you are indeed correct, my apologies, seems to stem from the weird thing by ending a sentence with `;` instead of `.` (not uncommon for pogrammers ;P ), which just seems like a comma after `"`. Did not know you could just comma-separate in a `COUNT(DISTINCT ..))` though, hence the kludgy `CONCAT()` in my answer, always nice to learn something new.

Comment: A quick question so I can walk away from this learning something -- the COUNT(DISTINCT email, ip_address) will count a record where the combination of the email AND ip are unique?  In my case unique to the comment_id since it's grouped, right?

Comment: @86Stang: yes=> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct (and see the reason why I used `CONCAT()` ;) )

Comment: @Wrikken: that's why I prefixed the set with the number of elements in my comment!

Comment: @86Stang: but note that this query won't count records with `NULL` in either of the fields (`ip_address` *or* `email`). Not sure if it's a problem for you.

Comment: @Quassnoi: yes, I'm just trying to find the lamest excuses for an obvious failing to read properly here ;P

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
     comment_id,
     COUNT(DISTINCT CONCAT(email,'|',ip_address))
FROM  log
GROUP BY comment_id
```

As OMG Ponies said, adding a unique in email+ip_address would help, possibly with this to prevent lost notes:

```
INSERT INTO log (...) VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY note = CONCAT(note,' ',VALUES(note));
```